# Not able to create standalone MySQL Docker Container in Azure AppService

Tags: mysql, azure, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am doing a Proof of Concept where in, I have 3 Azure App Service. Two of the App Service are API's and One of them has a MySql container. I am unable to get the App Service running with My Sql Container. I followed the example in this [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-multi-container) minus the Wordpress portion.

I tried to get the My Sql Portion of the container working. When I start the App Service, it starts My SQL Instance but get below error. Do not see any other information.
"INFO  - Stoping site MySqlTest because it failed during startup."

I am using the below docker compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
```

Comment: I didn't see any updates so that what is the status of your problem? Do you solve it? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple ways to create MySQl container deployed in Azure App Service, but had issues to get it working. I tried with Azure Container Instance and it worked fine!

Comment: Can you share your yml file? I get this error: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /opt/mysql/data

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the volume as well

```
db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Comment: Still getting the same error:   <br/>2019-12-03T13:26:14.535874785Z 2019-12-03T13:26:14.535826Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
  <br/>2019-12-03T13:26:14.535888485Z Version: '5.7.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
  <br/>2019-12-03T13:26:15.469174141Z 2019-12-03T13:26:15.469092Z 2 [Note] Got packets out of order
  <br/>2019-12-03 13:31:02.782 INFO  - Stoping site sdsadsad because it failed during startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the command in the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
```

The command will solve your current problem. In addition, I think the port you had exposed in the docker-compose file is not right. The MySQL listens to the port 3306 inside the container. So you need to expose the port 3306 for the container.

Comment: Hi Charles, I am getting the same error except for "Got packets out of order." But just an error as "Stoping site because it failed during startup." Also for port I had added WEBSITES_PORT 3306 entry in App Setting.

Comment: @Manu Do you add the command in the yaml file as my answer shows you?

Comment: Yes, I have added that command in the yaml file you had provided.

Comment: I deployed the My SQL image and setting the environment variables in Azure Container Instance rather than App Service and it just worked fine!  I am not sure on the problem with App Service but for now at least it allowed me to continue the work.Thanks!

Comment: @Manu That's great! Then you can accept it as the answer to help other communities who are looking for this.